# Arguments get mixed up with argparse

Tags: python, argparse, getopt

```
def main(argv):
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('p', 'projectType', type=str, help = 'c or c++ project type', choices=['c', 'c++']) 
parser.add_argument('i', 'inputfile', type=pathlib.Path, help = 'the input file path')
parser.add_argument('o',"outputfile",type=pathlib.Path, help= 'the output file path')
parser.add_argument
args = parser.parse_args()
```

when i run this code on command prompt, and enter the inputfile first for example..  it gives me an error. does Argparse have an option like getopt (where i call something with a letter before inputting it so no mix up ex, '-i ...input...').  Here this option is just for optional arguments.

Is there a way for positional arguments to do that?

Comment: Show us the actual command line that gives the error ("the inputfile first for example" is totally unclear). Then show us *what* error ("it gives me an error" is unclear). Then explain what command line you expect your parser to accept.

Comment: you want an `optional`  read the docs.  Also reread what it says about the `type` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [argparse documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method) you would define it as an "optional" argument but with the `required` flag set to true, e.g.:

```
parser.add_argument('-i', '--inputfile', required=True, type=pathlib.Path, help='the input file path')
```